# Is there a way to create a class thats can be called accross more than one project in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to do this so that I can access a certain part of the other linked project in all other projects. right now when I switch between projects I can only land on their entry points.

I have added a reference from my main project to two other dependent ones

Comment: Declaring a class `public` will allow you to call it from another project if you reference that project.

Comment: Also, Visual Basic or C#?

Comment: @PCLuddite - I think it says "C#" at least twice. :P

Comment: The answer to your question is _"yes"_.  For my next trick...

Comment: @Vilx- The title used to say "Visual Basic C#", which didn't make sense.

Comment: @PCLuddite - OK, sorry, I didn't notice that. The tags included only C# though.

Answer (score 0):

Put the common parts in a separate DLL (aka "Class Library" project in Visual Studio). Then add references to that project to the other projects where you need to use them. Don't forget to make the common classes public.

Answer (score 0):

In such case mostly people add one common project in there application and do stuff there which can be used in any other project to avoid the circular reference.
and of your public class will be available to any other project.